# How to populate the model of populated model in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I come from the MySQL background. I am new to MongoDB. How can I get the details model of a populated model? Please help me

#### Listing Model

```
var listing = new mongoose.Schema({
  ru_id : [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Rentable_unit' }],
  pro_id : [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Property' }]
})
```

#### Property Model

```
var property = new mongoose.Schema({
  address_id : [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Address' }],
  pro_authority : [{type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
})
```

#### Address Model

```
var address = new mongoose.Schema({
 address_line_1: { type: String },
 address_line_2: { type: String }
})
```

I need to get the data from listing address based on property how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to load your `listing`, then your `property` and then the `address` with three queries. It's referenced in the article below as `application-level join`.

If you need to do this a lot you should consider changing your schema design. You could check [this blog post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) from mongodb for possible solutions.